# SSRS Grouping based on parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to group my report based on a parameter but get the following error when I try to run the report

> The GroupExpression for the tablix 'Tablix1' contains an error: [BC30311] Value of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Parameter' cannot be converted to 'String'

The expression I have got so far is

```
=IIF(Parameters!ParameterName = "Name", Fields!Field1.Value 
        AND Fields!Field2.Value
        AND Fields!Field3.Value,
    Fields!Field2.Value 
        AND Fields!Field3.Value
    )
```

What I am expecting the above to do is if the Parameter = Name then group 3 different fields else if the parameter is anything but Name then group on only 2 fields, these 2 fields are also used in the first half of the IFF statement

I guess this is a datatype issue, if so then ideally I would like to fix it in SSRS NOT in the SQL stored procedure but if not then fixing it in SQL is not the end of the world

This may be a very simple question but pretty new to SSRS

Comment: I think you need to concatenate these fields as strings e.g.`Cstr(fields!Fields1.Value) + Cstr(Fields!Field2.value) + Cstr(Fields!Fields3.Value)  etc ..`

Comment: I am sure you could go in to the group properties and add 3 different groupings. So it would say in the details row grouping for example: group on, Field1, then Field 2 and then Field 3. In each of those separate expressions you could do what values you expect to see in each case. You should be able to use nothing as the else case in the last expression as you don't want another grouping at the end unless the parameter = "Name".

Comment: An example of the first expression to my previous comment is: `=IIF(Parameters!ParameterName = "Name", Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field2.Value)`. That would be the first grouping expression. When I say add 3 groupings I don't mean 3 individual parent groups. I mean 1 group that groups on 3 items in the group properties.

Comment: @arahman Not really sure that is best way to do it as my parameter can return 6 different values but only want to sort on 3 fields when it is a specific value otherwise just want to sort on the 2 fields. I think that if I can get MiguelH answer working that will be the cleanest option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
=IIF(Parameters!ParameterName = "Name", cstr(Fields!Field1.Value) + 
               cstr(Fields!Field2.Value) + cstr(Fields!Field3.Value),
               cstr(Fields!Field2.Value ) + cstr(Fields!Field3.Value)
)
```